# Comparing polylineZ elevation to DEM at various points along the line, not just the vertices

Tags: arcgis-pro, dem, elevation, 3d-analyst, profile

I have a polylineZ feature that represents sewer lines. I am looking for areas where points along the line may be above ground elevation, representing aerial lines. The problem is that I need to compare points along the line, maybe every 5-10 feet, not just the vertices.  If I only compare the elevation at the line vertices, these will usually be at ground elevation because they are where the manholes are located.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the 3D Analyst extension with ArcGIS Pro or with ArcGlobe/ArcScene/ArcMap?

Comment: I can use 3D Analyst with either Pro or ArcMap.  Thank you for responding!

Comment: as a workaround, you could use "densify" first.

Comment: I came up with a possible workflow, but would love feedback on this,  I have tested on a subset, but not for the entire dataset yet.   Run Add Z Information
 Run Stack Profile (generates a table with elevations of DEM along line every 10 feet)
 Join the Stack Profile table to the line feature by LINE_ID to FID
 Locate lines where the Z_Max from the line is greater than the Z value from the stack profile.